# How to refer to the first element of a tuple encapsulated in a single-case discriminated union

Tags: f#

Suppose you have a type like this:

```
type Corner = Corner of int*int
```

and then some variable:

```
let corner = Corner (1,1)
```

Is it possible to get the value of the first element of the tuple, something like:

```
fst corner
```

Looks like some kind of unwrapping to `int*int` is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The answer provided by @Foole is good, but from the comment I get the impression that you don't like having to 'declare' the temporary variable `first`. This can indeed feel cumbersome if all you want to do is to pull out the first value and then pipe it to another function.

There's no built-in facility that I'm aware of that lets you do this automatically. Consider that the `Corner` type given above is a degenerate case of a Discriminated Union (DU). Normally, DUs have more cases, and they are often heterogeneous in shape.

There can be good reasons to have a single-case DU such as `Corner`, but then it often makes sense to also supply various 'helper' functions to make working with that type smoother.

In the case of the `Corner` type, you could define functions such as:

```
let cornerX (Corner(x, _)) = x

let cornerY (Corner(_, y)) = y
```

Here, I've assumed that `Corner` models a coordinate, but if you'd like, you can also name the functions `fst` and `snd`. You can also put them in a dedicated module, if you rather prefer that.

This will enable you to extract and pipe a value from a `Corner` value without the hassle of a temporary variable:

```
> corner |> cornerX |> ((*) 10) |> string;;
val it : string = "10"
```

where `corner` is defined as in the OP.

Comment: Is it possible to get a generic version for any 2-tuple/n-tuple single case discriminated union?

Comment: @mbx I don't think so, because what's actually going on is pattern matching on a case constructor. In pattern matching, the name of the case constructor matters: it's actually a function. However, see the answer from @TheQuickBrownFox for a succinct inline alternative that doesn't require you to declare a `let`-bound function.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that was meant to be

```
type Corner = Corner of int*int
```

In which case, this will get the first value:

```
let (Corner(first,_)) = corner
```

Comment: thanks, I meant type for the type, yes :) However, this assignment means I'll need a temporary variable in order to use the member of the tuple (create first, than refer it)

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, it's not possible to get the first discriminated union case without naming it. But here's quite a concise way to do it:

```
Corner (1,1) |> function Corner (x,_) -> x
```

This uses the `function` keyword, which creates a function with one parameter and jumps straight into a pattern match on that parameter. Since there's only one case to match on it fits neatly into one line.